# Why do institutional investors hold ETPs like USO, XIV, TQQQ?

Tags: etf

Assume that any arbitrage opportunity can be arbitraged away instantly, and that they're not arbitraging.

1. Why don't institutional investors hold futures directly instead?
2. Why bear counterparty risk?
3. Why rely on USO, XIV to buy or sell futures at the optimum price, especially when USO held around 24% of June's contracts?

Comment: Do you have a source that suggests institutional investors rely on USO?

Comment: As of April 30, 2020 USO had 30% of its position in the July futures contract, 15% in August, 15% in September, 15% in October, 15% in December, and 10% in June 2021. Since the July contract becomes the front month in a few days they probably have already rolled out of July but the update is not yet on their website. In the case of USO I can almost answer the question by asking "why not invest in an un-leveraged holding of futures contracts ?".